# UIDeviceOrientationPortrait , ios 6 & 7 , InterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

i have this code i want to go to another uiview but i want to have showing this view (second view) in portrait mode only and the notification in first view doesn't work in second view  ;

is there any way to change the for this

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    view2 *viewController = [[[view2 alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];

    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

i want exactly one function same this  code in ios >6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing the UINavigationController and override the following methods :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: That’s strange!
Have you created the instance of new custom Navigation controller as below : 

    UINavigationController *navController = [[[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];

Comment: Yes , but how can i go to other navigation controler with codes